# Fuzzy Text Matching

Tags: c#, fuzzy-comparison

I need to attempt to match a given text to that in a database.

An example of this is:

Given Text: Acura MDX Technology Package

Databased items:

Tech Pkg
Technology Pkg with Navigation
Tech Pkg with Entertainment Pkg
Base
FWD
w/Technology Package/18" Wheels FWD

This doesn't have to 100% perfect, just a best guess.  Any libraries that I should pay special attention to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).

[More detail](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Is_there_a_way_to_use_a_proximity_operator_.28like_near_or_within.29_with_Lucene.3F) on making fuzzy queries.

And you can use the [Snowball Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.html) if you want to make it even fuzzier :)